# connecting to shared folder in windows with java

Tags: java, jcifs

I need to connect to a shared folder on a remote windows machine through java , where i put my domain authentication (username and password ) in the code , here is my code

```
 File file = new File("\\\\theRemoteIP\\webapps");   
    File[] files = file.listFiles();  
    System.out.println("access done");  

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)  
    {  
        String name = files[i].getName();  
        System.out.println(name);  
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: In Oracle Java 8 this works without problems.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should use [SmbFile](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html) and [NtlmPasswordAuthentication](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/NtlmPasswordAuthentication.html) from [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/). Here is a simple piece of code to show you how to do :

```
String url = "smb://yourhost/yourpath/";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "user", "password");
SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
for (SmbFile f : dir.listFiles())
{
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

Comment: NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "user", "password");

So the "user" , "password" are the domain authentication right ?

Comment: that's it. See the javadoc (linked in the answer) for more details.

Comment: If you're using a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention), make sure to have two extra forward slashes to indicate that it is a UNC path. For example `smb:////11.1.2.10/myFolder` or `smb:////myShare/myFolder`

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing open shared folders (i.e. username or password are not known or required),then you can follow the code below :

```
String path="smb://172.16.0.11/";

SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path);
String a[]=smbFile.list();
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```