# How can I watch a remote pc folder for changes in java?

Tags: java, networking, lan

I am working on project which looks up a remote directory for changes. I have been able to do this for a local folder using java watchservice. But for the remote directories it fails.
Is there any way in java through which I can watch a remote folder.
e.g. you watch a folder in your local area network for changes.

Comment: How often do you want to check for changes?

Comment: you need another watch list running at the server, and for any changes signal the local application.

Comment: you could check for a java implementation of samba/cifs http://jcifs.samba.org/

Comment: if it windows you can try this decision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171822/connecting-to-shared-folder-in-windows-with-java

Comment: @tom very frequently you can say every second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library which supports accessing network share on Windows platform. I am not sure if it supports "listening for changes" to the remote share. There is another project [JCifs Monitor](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/JCifs_Monitor) which may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [common-vfs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) to use same api for different filesystems.
I'm not sure that it can use events for your particular FS, but it provides abstraction, that can use poll internally and give you events for changes.