# JAVA: Access shared folder windows to solaris

Tags: java, windows, file, sunos

How I can access from my java program installed on a SunOS server to an ip address from a windows machine?

\xx.xx.x.x\folder\

File ficheroDirCompNav = new File(\\xx.xx.x.x\folder,name+".pdf");

The log in server shows Path /\xx.xx.x.x\name/XXX.pdf

How I can remove the symbol / and replace with \?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you answer may lie in a Similar Post [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171822/connecting-to-shared-folder-in-windows-with-java?rq=1

Comment: With replace the String that contains that symbol "/" works