# How to inject a network file resource with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

How can I tell `Spring` that the resource is supposed to be a network resource, and let it autowire accordingly?

```
@Value("\\MY-MACHINE\thefile.txt")
private Resource file;
```

Result:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [MY-MACHINE\thefile.txt] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your application is deployed on Windows. I don't have anywhere windows workstation to test it, but as far as I remember this is how it goes:

- create symbolic link to your network location:

  ```
  mklink /D C:\my-machine \\MY-MACHINE\
  ```
- refer to this symlink with absolute path:

```
@Value("file:///C:/my-machine/thefile.txt")
private Resource file;
```

Comment: This works great for local file, but how is the syntax for network fileS?

Comment: You can create symlink to this network location, so that file is visible as a local file. In Unix it's 'ln -s' in Windows take a look for examaple here: http://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

As nobody seems to be aware of, I found out that it's just necessairy to use double slashes like:

```
@Value("\\\\MY-MACHINE\\thefile.txt")
private Resource file;
```

In some cases you may required a `file:` statement before, like:
`file:\\\\MY-MACHINE\\thefile.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way using `classpath`

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Value("classpath:<path to file>")
private Resource file;
```

Comment: a network file is probably not on the classpath (hopefully, that would be nasty...)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a file on a Windows share will not work directly. See [connecting to shared folder in windows with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171822/connecting-to-shared-folder-in-windows-with-java) for more info on how to do that.