# LibreOffice 4.4.3 - Accessing Documents with jodconverter on different server

Tags: java, libreoffice, jodconverter

I´m running a simple Java Application (JDK 1.8). My main goal is to access a document (different formats), convert to PDF and then count the number of pages using PDFClown.

I can do it by introducing Documents on directory of my project (on my computer). The problem is when I try to access documents on another server.

> org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: could not load
>   document: Unsupported URL : "type detection failed"

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    OfficeManager officeManager = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration().buildOfficeManager();
    officeManager.start();
    String path = "\\\\serverIP\\documents\\test.doc";
    OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(officeManager);
    String outFile = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".pdf";
    converter.convert(new File(path), new File(outFile));
    Document document = new Document(new org.pdfclown.files.File(outFile));
    int countPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
    System.out.println(countPages);
    officeManager.stop();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access remote files this way using simple `File` class.

You must either [mount your folder as network drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive) and access file using normal file system path.

Or use special library to transfer files over SMB protocol without mounting.
See example here: [connecting to shared folder in windows with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171822/connecting-to-shared-folder-in-windows-with-java)