# Open password protected folder in file explorer using java app

Tags: java, authentication, passwords, microsoft-file-explorer

I would like to open a password protected NAS folder through IP address in windows 10 file explorer. I write my code in Java Eclipse.

I have a small code that opens the folder but then I have to write in username and password manually.

Is there a way to open the folder in file explorer already authenticated with given username and password?

[Authentication window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLS8E.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /n, /e, "+ip);
```

Comment: Related: [How to open password protected directory (in Windows) in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295958/how-to-open-password-protected-directory-in-windows-in-java)

Comment: @Lino I have found this answer but this is to open a specific file from location and use the data to console.
I want to open a folder in file explorer. I don't want to access a specific file with data.

Answer (score 0):

Using "net use" command I can teach the computer the username and admin for the authentication, then simply open the folder using explorer.exe

```
String ip = "\\\\192.168.10.199";
String user = "admin";
String pw = "admin";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net use " + ip + " /user:" + user + " " + pw);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /n, /e, "+ip);
```