# How to use Java NIO for writing files into network folder with specific credentials?

Tags: java, nio

I'm having some troubles in finding how to manage network credentials while writing file into my java application which is running on Tomcat on Windows Server 2012 R2.

What I need to do is write a file into a network folder with

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
//[...]
Files.write("//serverIp/serverFolder/fileName.xxx, fileToWrite);
```

but I need to do that with a specific username and password, which are specific for that use and with no password expiration, and different from the one used by Tomcat or the OS .

If not specified, I'm ofc getting `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: [...]`

I found that is possible with external libraries in others questions (like  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2171964/1984767 ) , but I prefer to stick to standard java whenever is possible.

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?

Comment: @Shubham nope, I've used an external library... But I still hope someone could give an answer to this!

Comment: I think it is not possible using Java NIO. External libraries or running windows (NET USE..) commands in java are the only options IMO.

Comment: Which library did you use?

Comment: @Shubham I've used https://www.jcifs.org/